# Spring Cache, how to delete another cached data when new data is cached?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, ehcache

Title might look weird but here is the question.

I am using ehcache on a spring boot application. I have a function that looks like this:

```
public Result foo(double value, String id){
    ...
    ...
    return convertValueToResult(value,id); 
}
```

Now what I need is this scenario: I want to cache this function so that if I receive the same id with the same value (literally the same arguments), I want to return the result from the cache without executing the function again.

However if I get the same id with different value, I want to re-execute the function, calculate the answer, cache it and **remove the previously cached data** with previous value.

How can I achieve this using @Cacheable, @CachePut or @CacheEvict annotations? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cache like a map. If do a put using the same key, it will overwrite the value.

in you above code you will have to use @Cacheable(key="#id")

Comment: But in that case, whenever I get the same id but **different value**, it will return the previously cached data, since they share the same key. But I want to re-execute the function with this new value.

Comment: you will then have to use the value also in the cache key which the @Cacheable Annotation does by default( remove the "key" from annotation), and use a TTL so that the cache expires after some time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For now, it seems like I dont have any other option to wait for that data to expire automatically by using TTL.